# Can't unwrap Optional.None. i can't figure out how or what

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have looked over multiple pages here on Stack Overflow and can't wrap my head around it sadly. Maybe its the heat. Don't know. Anyway, could anyone please help me and explain how to unwrap?

It breaks at:

```
self.txt = dict.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as NSMutableArray!
```

in:

```
var dict1: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var txt: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var dict: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hovedMenu", ofType: "plist")
    self.dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    self.txt = dict.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as NSMutableArray!
    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

***UPDATE***

```
 let textArray = dict.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as? NSMutableArray
    if let textArray = dict.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as? NSMutableArray {
        self.txt = textArray
        println("txt\(txt)")
    } else {
        println("txt\(txt)")
    }
```

still doesn't work

Comment: I would recommend watching the first 20 minutes of `Intermmediate Swift` WWDC video, it will clear things all up for you, I promise!

Comment: What line is it crashing on? What is the exact error message?

Comment: @AlexWayne see above edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dict.valueForKey("menuPunkt")` returns an optional `NSMutableArray`, which you're unwrapping with the exclamation point at the end of that line. If you unwrap it more gracefully you can handle the condition where `dict` doesn't contain a value for `"menuPunkt"`:

```
if let textArray = dict.valueForKey("menuPunkt") as? NSMutableArray {
    self.txt = textArray
} else {
    // give self.text some sort of default value
}
```

Comment: hmm if i use your code, it doesn't get read when i run the app ?
do i need to call the if statement somewhere or use textArray instead of txt ?

Comment: Sorry, I had `self.text` instead of `self.txt` there. It's not getting read because `hovedMenu.plist` doesn't have a value for the `"menuPunkt"` key. That's why you were getting an error before, too. Check your .plist file to make sure it has what you're looking for.

Comment: Or perhaps it's not finding the .plist file at all - try debugging right after you load the `NSDictionary` and make sure you got what you're expecting.

Comment: Okey figured out that it can't find my plist... so far so good. how ever from that code i provided how can it NOT find the plist ?
it should be in the mainBundle

Comment: That's a whole different question! :)

Comment: @NateCool yea i know :) ohh well i'm off to write yet another question then :) thx for the help, i'll accept it

Comment: actually it doesn't work at all. now i got it to get my plist and i can see the data. now i need only the menuPunkt string from the plist. had to read it with NSMutableArray instead of NSDir...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55335/discussion-between-nate-cook-and-kennyvb).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because the method you are calling is returning `nil`. When you use ! with an optional variable (a variable that can be nil), which that method returns, you are basically asserting that the object is not nil. if the object is nil, you will get a runtime error like you are seeing